# Who pays for Cisco's and Caitlin's salaries in season 2?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Now that Wells is out of the picture, who pays for their salaries? They don't appear to have another job.

I know that Wells left STAR Labs to Barry, but I don't think he has enough money to pay them with his CSI job.

Comment: probably the same non-existent person that was paying their salaries in S1. STAR Labs was officially shutdown so where did Wells get his operating budget?

Comment: Caitlin actually *was* working for another lab at the start of the season. It's not entirely clear if she left that job completely.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I always assumed Wells was loaded and he was using his own money for that. In this season noone has that much cash.

Comment: wells set up a trust for barry. it's entirely possible that he also set up a trust to keep the lights on until barry took ownership, and likely an included inheritance.

Comment: @Deleteman I assumed all the money Wells would have had came from grants, which would have dried up once he stopped running experiments. Theoretical physicists are rarely "loaded", and I suspect he was getting sued a lot after the accident. Where he got the money to set up a trust fund, I have no idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Arrow&Flash wiki Caitlin Snow works  at  Mercury Labs. As of Cisco Ramon wiki did not update his work status and it is still shown as "Mechanical engineer at S.T.A.R. Labs"  but in 2nd episode of 2nd season  Detective Joe West gives him police badge which might imply that he is working full time for police in their new meta-human squad. He also helped Joe in first episode of second season building him weapon to stop Atom-Smasher

Comment: Oh you're right! I forgot about that part! So I'm guessing Cisco is "officially" working for the police department. Thanks!

Comment: It appears so..

Comment: Don't forget, STAR Labs is also still receiving profit from any and all products they have produced and technologies they have developed.  Since Wells left everything to Barry, Barry pretty much has control of Wells's personal money and is in control of STAR Labs as well.  So chances are, Barry, or STAR Labs is probably still paying Cisco and Caitlin as well.